# Java Can't Open a File with Surrogate Unicode Values in the Filename?

Tags: java, file, unicode, filenames, surrogate-pairs

I'm dealing with code that does various IO operations with files, and I want to make it able to deal with international filenames. I'm working on a Mac with Java 1.5, and if a filename contains Unicode characters that require surrogates, the JVM can't seem to locate the file. For example, my test file is:

`"草鷗外.gif"` which gets broken into the Java characters `\u8349\uD85B\uDFF6\u9DD7\u5916.gif`

If I create a file from this filename, I can't open it because I get a FileNotFound exception. Even using this on the folder containing the file will fail:

```
File[] files = folder.listFiles(); 
for (File file : files) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Failed to find File"); //Fails on the surrogate filename
    }
}
```

Most of the code I am actually dealing with are of the form:

```
FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("草鷗外.gif"));
// operations follow
```

Is there some way I can address this problem, either escaping the filenames or opening files differently?

Comment: What's the value of Charset.defaultCharset() in your environment?

Comment: (Unfortunately, StackOverflow also has a problem with surrogates, and has stripped the U+26FF6 ideograph from the question)

Comment: Can you provide what System.getProperty("file.encoding") returns? Try changing your encoding java -dfile.encoding=ENCODING_GOES_HERE if does nor work change your system locale. If this also does nor work we will wait for an expert to solve it.

Comment: The charset and file encoding are both UTF-8

Answer (score 7):

I suspect one of Java or Mac is using [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#CESU-8) instead of proper UTF-8. Java uses “modified UTF-8” (which is a slight variation of CESU-8) for a variety of internal purposes, but I wasn't aware it could use it as a filesystem/defaultCharset. Unfortunately I have neither Mac nor Java here to test with.

“Modified” is a modified way of saying “badly bugged”. Instead of outputting a four-byte UTF-8 sequence for supplementary (non-BMP) characters like 𦿶:

```
\xF0\xA6\xBF\xB6
```

it outputs a UTF-8-encoded sequence for each of the surrogates:

```
\xED\xA1\x9B\xED\xBF\xB6
```

This isn't a valid UTF-8 sequence, but a lot of decoders will allow it anyway. Problem is if you round-trip that through a real UTF-8 encoder you've got a different string, the four-byte one above. Try to access the file with that name and boom! fail.

So first let's just check how filenames are actually stored under your current filesystem, using a platform that uses bytes for filenames such as Python 2.x:

```
$ python
Python 2.x.something (blah blah)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.')
```

On my filesystem (Linux, ext4, UTF-8), the filename “草𦿶鷗外.gif” comes out as:

```
['\xe8\x8d\x89\xf0\xa6\xbf\xb6\xe9\xb7\x97\xe5\xa4\x96.gif']
```

which is what you want. If that's what you get, it's probably Java doing it wrong. If you get the longer six-byte-character version:

```
['\xe8\x8d\x89\xed\xa1\x9b\xed\xbf\xb6\xe9\xb7\x97\xe5\xa4\x96.gif']
```

it's probably OS X doing it wrong... does it always store filenames like this? (Or did the files come from somewhere else originally?) What if you rename the file to the ‘proper’ version?:

```
os.rename('\xe8\x8d\x89\xed\xa1\x9b\xed\xbf\xb6\xe9\xb7\x97\xe5\xa4\x96.gif', '\xe8\x8d\x89\xf0\xa6\xbf\xb6\xe9\xb7\x97\xe5\xa4\x96.gif')
```

Comment: Not really a bug as it's part of the spec (even if it is often confusing.)

Comment: The result of the python commands was the proper filename you listed first, so it must be Java not playing nice.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. Even if you detected the broken-CESU-8 situation, I can't think of any way to work around it and get a byte-oriented filename interface. :-( You might have to explicitly disallow the surrogates until such time as Sun fix it. How poor.

Answer (score 5):

If your environment's default locale does not include those characters you cannot open the file.

See: [File.exists() fails with unicode characters in name](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4733494)

**Edit:**
Alright.. What you need is to change the system locale. Whatever OS you are using.

**Edit**:

See: [How can I open files containing accents in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072376/how-can-i-open-files-containing-accents-in-java)

See: [JFileChooser on Mac cannot see files named by Chinese chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072619/jfilechooser-on-mac-cannot-see-files-named-by-chinese-chars)

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without changing the system locale? The program I am building will need to run on any locale, and I should be able to input these characters and deal with these files even in a US/English locale.

Comment: Bad solution - because app runned on users, wich not sitting on my computer. And have different locale, and they do not have rigth administrator to do this.

Comment: AFAIK there is no other solution. This limitation comes with Sun/Oracle Java. You can try JFileChooser if displaying a save dialog to your users is OK for you.

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be a problem with the Mac JVM (tested on 1.5 and 1.6). Filenames containing supplementary characters / surrogate pairs cannot be accessed with the Java File class. I ended up writing a JNI library with Carbon calls for the Mac version of the project (ick). I suspect the CESU-8 issue bobince mentioned, as the JNI call to get UTF-8 characters returned a CESU-8 string. Doesn't look like it's something you can really get around.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the old-skool java File api, maybe just on a mac?  Anyway, the new java.nio api works much better.  I have several files containing unicode characters and content that failed to load using java.io.File and related classes.  After converting all my code to use [java.nio.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) EVERYTHING started working.  And I replaced org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils (which has the same problem) with [java.nio.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)...

...and be sure to read and write the content of file using an appropriate charset, for example: Files.readAllLines(myPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)