# How to fix java when if refused to open a file with special character in filename?

Tags: java, linux, file-io

How to open a file, with a special character which Java refused to open?

At the beginning I guess it was a charset encoding problem as I read the filename wrong from a log file. But later I found that, it is possible a bug of JVM and I need a workaround.

Real example better then words

```
import java.io.*;
public class WTF{
        public static void main(String[] s)throws Exception{
                File f2=new File(".");
                for (File subFile : f2.listFiles()) {
                        System.out.println(subFile.getName());
                        System.out.println(subFile.exists());
                        System.out.println(new FileInputStream(subFile));
                }
        }
}
```

With a result

```
[USER@SERVER ZZZ]$ java -cp . WTF
WTF.class
true
java.io.FileInputStream@732dacd1
WTF.java
true
java.io.FileInputStream@3bad086a
ABC_�%81DEF.txt
false
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ABC_�%81DEF.txt (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at WTF.main(WTF.java:8)
```

And the folder contains

```
[USER@SERVER ZZZ]$ ls -lb
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER GROUP    8 Apr 14 20:54 ABC_\303%81DEF.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER GROUP 1068 Apr 14 20:58 WTF.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER GROUP  554 Apr 14 20:58 WTF.java
```

Comment: Is the output you show really from the class WTF? I looks like it is coming from another class 'C'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be related to [File.exists() fails with unicode characters in name](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4733494)

Comment: +1 - the cure would be to change the OS locale settings so that it used an file encoding that was compatible with the characters in the filename.

Comment: Again another example that Sun Micro-system do never fix bug for years. Is it really so hard to accept and to agree a bug?

Comment: I am thinking what value of LC_ALL I should use. As that bug report page will never provide any useful information. May be all of us should learn from Adrian http://www.techgoss.com/Story/3226S14-Dedication-to-open-source.aspx

Comment: Anyone call tell if NIO2 in Java7 fix the bug or the bug still there?

Comment: While Dennis' exact use-case is not the same as mine, java.nio.file fixed the related problems I was having. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072376/how-can-i-open-files-containing-accents-in-java

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to use a system command to either rename or link to the file using only standard "friendly" chars. Seems hacky but I would think it would work.