# FileNotFoundException when trying to read the listFiles that system provides me. Is it a name encoding problem?

Tags: java, file, tomcat, encoding

I'm using tomcat 5.5.28 in a windows machine with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in JAVA_OPTS.

I have a problem reading files from the file system, this is my code:

```
File directory = new File(directoryPath);
if (directory.exists()) {
    File[] fileInDir = directory.listFiles();
    for (int i=0; i<fileInDir.length; i++) {
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(fileInDir[i]);
        ...
    }
}
```

It works fine if the file doesn't contain any "strange" character.
If the directory contains a file with acute/tilde whithin his name, when I try to create the FileInputStream I get FileNotFoundException.

I solve it using a decoded String instead of a File object, doing this:

```
String name = new String(fileInDir[i].getName().getBytes(), System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
String parent = new String(fileInDir[i].getParent().getBytes(), System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

Charset systemCharset = Charset.forName(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
CharsetDecoder systemDecoder = systemCharset.newDecoder();
CharBuffer cbufN = systemDecoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(name.getBytes()));
CharBuffer cbufP = systemDecoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(parent.getBytes()));
String path = cbufP.toString() + File.separator + cbufN.toString();

FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(path);
```

It works in my windows machine, I can read files like (X:\directory\zípìç\ñañaf.txt) without problems:

I moved this code to other enviroment: a linux machine with same tomcat version (5.5.28), same java virtual machine version (1.6.0_20), same file.encoding option (UTF-8),... and I get again FileNotFoundException.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any assistance.
Juan Arcadio.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the path you construct in your workaround code (in both environments)?

```
System.out.println("Path: "+path);
```

Other than that I would advice to make use of an API like Apache Commons IO or similar.

**EDIT:**

If I'm not mistaken you're question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663709/how-to-fix-java-when-if-refused-to-open-a-file-with-special-charater-in-filename/5664031#5664031). See if the workaround in there helps (changing your unix/linux system's locale).

And if you have anything to say in this I would always advice against using spaces and special characters/glyphs like tilde etc in filenames. From the looks of it it's about a www (web) folder; in that case using spaces etc is pure madness.

Comment: I doubt Commons IO would help any on this occasion.

Comment: Admittedly so. But Java's IO (in particular versions) has a bad reputation to say the least. Hence the advice.

Comment: The path name is wrong, is like this:

win - Path: C:\www\compartida\carpetón
linux - /www/compartida/carpet�

Using commons io from Apache, in windows works fine without doing any String conversion only using File objects.

`FileInputStream fileInput = FileUtils.openInputStream(fileInDir[i]);`

but in Linux enviroment I get `FileNotFoundException` for files containing some special characters in their name. Any suggestion?

Comment: And what path is constructed in Linux (with or without Apache IO)?

Comment: The path that I constructed doing String conversions is the same that Apache IO constructed in Linux.

When it throws exception with my own path conversion print: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /www/compartida/carpet� (No such file or directory)`


When it throws exception with Apache IO print: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/www/compartida/carpet�' does not exist`

Comment: Thanks, I will discuss it with the administrators of the Linux System to test changing system locale.