# How to decode a path and open related file?

Tags: java, ruby, utf-8, utf8-decode

I'm trying to parse an iTunes XML library file on Mac OS.

In the iTunes file I have this string:

```
<key>Location</key>
<string>file://localhost/home/user/Downloads/album/01%C4%2024%5F7%20%28Intro%29%20&#38;.mp3</string>
```

As you can see it appears to be URL encoded. Now, the next step is to find and read this file on the filesystem, but it seems I cannot find a proper way to do that with Java or Ruby.

My main goal is to do that in Java, but for the sake of simplicity I tried this in Ruby:

```
2.0.0p247 :003 > URI.decode(str)
 => "file://localhost/home/user/Downloads/album/01\xC4 24_7 (Intro) &#38;.mp3" 
2.0.0p247 :004 > CGI.unescape(str)
 => "file://localhost/home/user/Downloads/album/01\xC4 24_7 (Intro) &#38;.mp3"
```

The file appears in the file manager as `/home/user/Downloads/album/01Ä 24_7 (Intro) &.mp3`

Java:

```
  path = URLDecoder.decode( originalPath, "ISO-8859-1" );
  --
  path = URLDecoder.decode( originalPath, "UTF-8" );
  --
  path = new java.net.URI(originalPath).getPath();
```

But I cannot find the file using the resulting `path` in code. `exists()` or `isFile()` are always false although in the debugger the path shows up correctly.

How should I proceed?

Sadly I'm not fetching a file name from the OS, but from an XML file. Am I hitting a long standing JVM bug?

- [How can I open files containing accents in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072376/how-can-i-open-files-containing-accents-in-java)
- [How to fix java when if refused to open a file with special charater in filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663709/how-to-fix-java-when-if-refused-to-open-a-file-with-special-charater-in-filename)

Setting the JVM to a specific locale is not acceptable, because I don't need to open only files in the user's locale.

Comment: First of all, the numeric entity reference `&#38;` should be turned into `&` in the XML parser. Which parser are you using?

Comment: I'm using SAXParser to read the file: https://github.com/codercowboy/iTunesUtilities/blob/master/src/com/worldsworstsoftware/xmltagparser/SimpleXMLTagParser.java#L124 and get a location back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with LANG env variable.