# File isDirectory() method always returns false when folder name contains special chars

Tags: java, linux

I always get a false return from `isDirectory()` method when the folder name contains specials chars like `ó` or `ñ`.

The Java code works fine in DOS, I have the problem executing jar in my NAS (Linux).

```
public static void listarDirectorio(File f, String separador)
        throws Exception {

    File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();
    File ficheroTratado = null;

    for (int x = 0; x < ficheros.length; x++) {

        ficheroTratado = null;
        ficheroTratado = ficheros[x].getCanonicalFile();

        if (!ficheroTratado.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Checking file: " + ficheroTratado.getName());
            if (esBorrable(ficheroTratado.getName())) {
                System.out.println(
                        "File can be erased: " + ficheroTratado.getName());
            }
        }else if (!ficheros[x].getName().startsWith("@")) {

            String nuevo_separador;
            nuevo_separador = separador + " # ";
            listarDirectorio(ficheros[x], nuevo_separador);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: what JDK are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix java when if refused to open a file with special charater in filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663709/how-to-fix-java-when-if-refused-to-open-a-file-with-special-charater-in-filename)

Comment: How do you execute code on a NAS? Do you mean that you run it on some system on storage connected to the nAS? What system?

Comment: Mureinik i'm developing in Windows with eclipse, java version "1.7.0_25"

Comment: @rrnieto sounds a lot like http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4899439, but it was supposed to be solved in 6u3.

Comment: bmargulies i have a .sh who calls the .jar in the NAS operating system. Is a linux based, Synology DSM 4.3.

Comment: Finally the solution to this problem was set the correct locale values in the NAS operating System.