# Accessing Files whose Names are With an unknown Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, filenames, nio

When walking the file tree of a linux machine (perhaps also other Unix), I can encounter files or dirs names who are encoded with different encodings than the one returned by Java's default charset (Charset.defaultCharset()).
This is due to the fact that a user can change he's locale and write a file or dir who's name is encoded with the user's custom locale.

I want to walk the entire file system, (for example using Files.walkFileTree) and for each file/dir encountered always be able to store something so that I can later create a new Path object successfully to that file/dir.

However if I encounter a file/dir whose name is encoded with an unknown encoding I am unable to access that file again.

To demonstrate the problem, on a RHEL6 machine I have a dir under "/home/languages" whose name is encoded with encoding he_IL.iso88598 and the locale of the system is also he_IL.iso88598
The following code decodes the name once as it should using the platform's default encoding and once as UTF-8:

```
Path source = Paths.get("/home/languages");

Files.walkFileTree(source, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

@Override
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
        BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

    String badName = new String(dir.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));
    String name = dir.toString();
    Files.exists(Paths.get(name));                  
    Files.exists(Paths.get(badName))
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

});

The following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters: /home/languages/?¢??¨??×
```

Java is able to access files/dirs even if their encoding is unknown once during the walkFileTree so why can't I access those paths again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see this discussion:
[How can I open files containing accents in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072376/how-can-i-open-files-containing-accents-in-java)

and this:
[How to fix java when if refused to open a file with special charater in filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663709/how-to-fix-java-when-if-refused-to-open-a-file-with-special-charater-in-filename)

old bug known in File library

advice to use java.nio.file package (Files and Paths)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @guillaume, however I don't think I am using File or any other java.io library. I updated the question to be more specific.