# Java File.renameTo(File) not working

Tags: java, file-io, rename

I'm trying to list a directory's contents, and rename certain files.

```
public void run(String dirName) {
    try {
        File parDir = new File(dirName);
        File[] dirContents = parDir.listFiles();

        // Rename if necessary
        for(File f : dirContents) {
            System.out.println("f is:\n" + f.toString());
            String name = f.getName();
            String subbedName = name.replaceAll("\uFFFD", "_");

            System.out.println("\n" + "name = " + name + ", subbedName = " + subbedName + "\n");

            if(!name.equals(subbedName)) {
                File newFile = new File(f.getParentFile(), subbedName);
                System.out.println("newFile is:\n" + newFile.toString());
                if(!f.renameTo(newFile))
                    System.out.println("Tried to change file name but couldn't.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc1) {
        System.out.println("Something happened while listing and renaming directory contents: " + exc1.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get "`Tried to change file name but couldn't.`" I don't *believe* that Java is considering these files to be "open", so I don't think that's the reason. I've even ran `chmod 777 myDir` where `myDir` is the value of the `dirName` string passed into the `run` method.

What am I missing here? Why won't Java rename these file(s)? These are CentOS machines.

**Edit**: Added printouts for both `f` and `newFile`, which is as follows:

```
f is:
/root/path/to/mydir/testï¿½.txt

newFile is:
/root/path/to/mydir/test_.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your new `File` object with the *full* pathname of those files. So

```
String name = f.getName(); // gets the name without the directory
```

should likely be:

```
String name = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

(your search/replace may need to change)

Comment: Thanks @Brian Agnew (+1) - I followed your suggestion but am getting the same result. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `f.getName()` returns the last name component of the path that is represented by `f`.  You then massage this String and turn it back into a `File`.  But the `File` now represents a path relative to the current directory, not the directory containing the original path.

As a result your code is actually attempting to rename the files from `dirName` into the application's current directory.  That could fail because files already exist in the current directory with those names, or because the `dirName` and the current directory are in different file systems.  (You cannot rename a file from one filesystem to another ... you have to *copy* it.)

Please note that a `File` in Java represents a pathname, not a file or a folder.  In your code, the `f` objects are the pathnames for file system objects (either files or folders) in the directory denoted by the String `dirname`.  Each of these `f` objects *will* have a directory part.

---

There is more than one way to fix your code; for example

- change `name = f.getName()` to `name = f.toString()`
- change `new File(subbedName)` to `new File(f.getParentFile(), subbedName)`

---

I have an alternative / additional theory.

The pathname of the file containing the `\uFFFD` character is coming out as "mojibake"; i.e. the kind of garbled text that you get when you display encoded text using the wrong encoding.  And since we are seeing 3 characters of garbled text, I suspect that it is attempting to display the UTF-8 rendering of `\uFFFD` as Latin-1.

So my theory is that the same think is happening when the `File.renameTo` method is converting `f` to the form that it is going to provide to the system call.  For some reason that is no clear to me, Java could be using the wrong encoding, and as a result producing a "name" for the original file that doesn't match the name of the file in the file system.  That would be sufficient to cause the rename to fail.

Possibly related questions / links:

- [File name charset problem in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832761/file-name-charset-problem-in-java)
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4733494  (Note that Sun decided this was not a Java bug, and most of the "me too" comments on the bug report are from people who do not understand the explanation ...)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C (+1) - I appreciate your help but neither of these suggestions are working.  Still getting the "Tired to change file name but couldn.t'" printout...

Comment: Print out `f` and the `File` you are trying to rename it to when it fails and add that to your Question.

Comment: Thanks again - please see my edits (added code/printouts for `f` and `newFile` and added their output to the bottom of the question).

Answer (score 1):

`f.getName();` only returns the name of the folder, not the full path. So `subbedName` becomes a relative path file. Try something with `f.getCanonicalPath()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @sp00m (+1) - please see my comment underneath Brian Agnew's answer - I have the same question for you. Thanks again!