# Java File can't open certain files

Tags: java, windows, file, unicode, io

I'm trying to open files from within Java with something like this:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\coolfile.txt");
```

Of course it all works fine and dandy in most cases.

HOWEVER!

When I have a file with the unicode character `u3000`, I cannot open it! Even if the file exists.

For example:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\coolfile\u3000withweirdname.txt");
```

I get an Exception, EVEN WHEN THE FILE EXISTS

```
[java] java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/E:/_prog/test%E3%80%80.txt. Error message: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Please help me i tried pretty much everything. This is driving me insane :/

Edit:

To give some more info:

I can easily create file with this name from Java.

It seems it has something to do with whitespace

I don't know if it applies to other characters; I didn't find any yet. But of course if there's 1 there could easily be 100.

I'm pretty sure I can't read from the file or write to it from Java, but I haven't tested that since it isn't my main concern.

Comment: Is that cut and paste? i.e. do your filename string really have single '\' chars in them?

Comment: You need to double the "\" like java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\coolfile\\u3000withweirdname.txt");

Comment: \u3000 is how to write unicode char u3000. i think so at least

Comment: RealHowTo no thats wrong. That would just give me \u3000 in the path which i dont need at all. I need the UNICODE CHARACTER u3000 in the path.

Comment: Can you guys please read the question. It seems like u assume i made some simple stupid mistake but like i said i tried almost everything.

Comment: Could check 'new File("c:\\coolfile\u3000withweirdname.txt").exists() ?

Comment: @user1258312 Give an SSCCE for others to help you, and also state what all you have tried

Comment: Ok i don't know what SSCCE is, but i appreciate all the help i can get.

Comment: And i posted the exception now

Comment: Oh yeah maybe i should say im using Windows XP.

Comment: Check whether (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610013/file-listfiles-mangles-unicode-names-with-jdk-6-unicode-normalization-issues) is related to your problem

Comment: And this also (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545625/java-cant-open-a-file-with-surrogate-unicode-values-in-the-filename)

Comment: Yes i think it is related. I searched through stackoverflow before posting and i read that thread and tried the solution. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe you can modify their solution to solve my problem, but im not smart enough for that =(

Comment: Yes i read that one too!

Comment: I think they are related 100%, but WHERE IS THE SOLUTION? :(

Comment: 1) Make some changes for debugging!  `File f = new File("c:\\coolfile\u3000withweirdname.txt"); System.out.println("Exists: " + f.exists() ); //is it real path?` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that is the top-hit on Google for the term quoted earlier, please don't expect people to spoon-feed information to you.  3) The quoted code would not compile, so please stop wasting our time, if not your own.

Comment: This is not a Java problem, it is an awt one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think i actually found a kind of solution to my question and i post it here to help any people that may have similar problems.

This fix only works for Windows (XP and up i think) BUT i don't even know if this problem exist in other OS. And even if it does a similar fix should be possible.

I am using the following code to succesfully open a file with the character:

Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c start \"\" \"E:\_prog\test\u3000.txt\"").start();

Which opens the file 'E:_prog\testu3000.txt'

Comment: oh and btw thx to muCommander, i stole the fix from their program

Answer (score 1):

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\coolfile\u3000withweirdname.txt");
```

That doesn't compile. Clearly it isn't your real code.

> [java] java.io.IOException: Failed to open
>   file:/E:/_prog/test%E3%80%80.txt

And there is proof. Clearly you passed a URL to new `FileInputStream()`. It doesn't take a URL string, it takes a file name.

Comment: "Clearly you passed a URL to new FileInputStream()" this is wrong. I got the file path from calling getFiles() on a folder

Comment: @user1258312 Not proven. Show us the code. Where did the file:// and the %-escapes come from if it wasn't a URL?

Comment: i don't know know i assumed it would come when formatting the exception for display or something. I realize now i should have made a compilable example. The reason i did not post the project is that its way too big and would just clutter the discussion up.

Comment: ok man i posted a fix now. I might have made some dumb mistake somewhere else but trust me i didn't enter URL i entered correct file name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know \u3000 is ideographic space character. To test your code I created a file with name CompanyAlt+3000Address.

Note: when you press Alt+3000, windows will create an ideographic space character. Then I copied the file name, to my java program and it worked for me.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\Chandru\\Desktop\\Company╕Address.txt"));
```

Comment: There might be something wrong with my windows. Alt+3000 gives me ©

Comment: And if i copy your ╕ i get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: c:\tstâ••.txt doesn't exist." when trying to open c:\test  .txt

Comment: ╕ it should work dear, even I am using Windows XP. Even while typing the comment I pressed Alt+3000 and it give me ╕ symbol.