# Java UTF-8 filenames with IBM JVM (AIX)

Tags: java, utf-8, aix, j9

I'm having trouble understanding the way the IBM JVM's implementation of `java.io.File` deals with UTF-8 on AIX on the JFS2 filesystem.  I suspect there's a system property that I'm overlooking, but I have not yet been able to find it.

Let's assume I have a file named `othér` (where `é` is U+00E9 or UTF-8 bytes`0xc3 0xa9`).  The filename is encoded in UTF-8, and was created by a C program:

```
char filename[] = { 'o', 't', 'h', 0xc3, 0xa9, 'r', 0 };
open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
```

If I create a Unicode string in Java that is representative of the filename, it fails to open it.  Further, if I use `File.listFiles()` in Java, it insists on treating this as a Latin1 string.  For example:

```
String expectedName = new String(new char[] { 'o', 't', 'h', 0xe9, 'r' });
File expected = new File(expectedName);
if (expected.exists())
    System.out.println(expectedName + " exists");
else
    System.out.println(expectedName + " DOES NOT exist");

for (File child : new File(".").listFiles())
{
    System.out.println(child.getName());
    System.out.print("Chars:");
    for (char c : child.getName().toCharArray())
        System.out.print(" 0x" + Integer.toHexString((int)c));
    System.out.println();
}
```

The results of this program are:

```
% java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 FileTest
othér DOES NOT exist
othÃ©r
Chars: 0x6f 0x74 0x68 0xc3 0xa9 0x72
```

So it appears that my filenames are getting treated as Latin1.  I've tried setting the [`file.encoding`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/sysprop2.htm) system property to `UTF8` and the [`client.encoding.override`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzatz/51/admin/help/trun_svr_utf.html) system property to `UTF-8` to no avail.  My `LANG` and `LC_ALL` settings are `en_US.UTF-8`:

```
% echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
% echo $LC_ALL
en_US.UTF-8
```

My system's "Primary Language Environment", as configured by SMIT, is "ISO8859-1".  I don't really know the full impact this setting has, but I cannot change it.  I suspect that if I *could* change this to "UTF8 English" then that *may* fix the problem, but since JFS2 stores filenames in Unicode and Java operates in Unicode internally, I feel like there should be a more general solution to the problem.

Is there another system property to J9 that I can set that will make force it to use UTF-8 filenames regardless of my SMIT setting?

AIX version is 5.2, Java version is IBM J9 (1.5.0), filesystem is JFS2:

```
rs6000% uname -a
AIX rs6000 2 5 000A9B7C4C00
rs6000% java -version
java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap32dev-20091106a (SR11 ))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223-20091104 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20091103_45935_bHdSMr
JIT  - 20091016_1845_r8
GC   - 20091026_AA)
JCL  - 20091106
rs6000% mount|grep /home
         /dev/hd1         /home            jfs2   Jun 27 16:02 rw,log=/dev/hd8
```

Update: this still occurs on Java6:

```
% java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260sr11-20120806_01(SR11))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32 jvmap3260sr11-20120801_118201 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20120801_118201
JIT  - r9_20120608_24176ifx1
GC   - 20120516_AA)
JCL  - 20120713_01
```

Comment: Does `java` on AIX pick up the encoding from the locale, like it does on other Unixes? Try running the test program as `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 java FileTest`

Comment: It does not.  I forgot to include that above.  *However*, it's possible that UTF-8 is not valid or not installed and my `LANG` and `LC_ALL` settings are being ignored, but my lack of familiarity with SMIT makes this difficult to determine fully.

Comment: Check this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545625/java-cant-open-a-file-with-surrogate-unicode-values-in-the-filename). AFAIK there are problems in Java with opening files which filename encoding differs from the system locale.

Comment: Just to be sure - when you run `ls` - the output is `othér`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. I really am trying to help here.

[This is a blog post about your actual issue. I promise.](http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/24/java-platform-encoding/)

Try running your program with the `-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8` flag set.

Comment: Strings are not latin1 in Java, they are sequences of UTF-16 code-units.  The two expressions you show are equivalent, with the exception that the second won't compile until you put in `(byte)` casts, and the first won't compile until you add a single `(char)` cast.

Comment: They're not Latin1.  They're Unicode code points.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])

Comment: @durron597: I think you're mistaken, initializing a `String` with a `char[]` of Unicode code points is correct.

Comment: Creating a string that *should* represent the filename is not the problem.  Creating a string that *accurately* represents the filename *is* the problem.  The previous article you link to discusses how the Mac OS filesystem stores filenames as canonically decomposed always.  This is not the issue here.

Comment: I'll be damned.  It really does.  I need to look into this more, but yes, I think that the `sun.jnu.encoding` system property does indeed affect the behavior.

Comment: @DeepakBala: I was equally dubious.  But the IBM JVM does indeed read that system property.

Comment: That is interesting. I cant find any reliable documentation on this property yet. I guess this is another one of those software issues that we can file under 'It works, but I don't know why' :)

Comment: @durron597: just need to do a bit more testing - but do have an upvote in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

See here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/aix/118/README.html for a list of valid AIX locales
Your exports should look like this i think

```
  export LC_ALL=EN_US
  export LANG=EN_US
```

Comment: My reading of that would indicate that en_US is ISO-8859-1 (aka "Latin 1") not UTF-8.

Comment: The case seems to matter . EN_US is listed as UTF8 while en_us is as ISO8859_1

Comment: what does the output of  the command "locale -a" gives you? You should see en_US and its alias en_US.8859_1 as well as EN_US and its alias EN_US.UTF-8. It's seems stupid that two different cases refer to two different encoding but it seems to be so.

Comment: Gah, apparently `UTF-8` is not even installed.  I hadn't even thought to look at `locale -a`, thank you.  Suddenly things make more sense.  Unfortunately, I'm not the administrator.  And thank you for pointing out the casing in that document, I hadn't noticed that there was indeed a difference between `en_US` and `EN_US`.

Comment: Can you confirm that with your locale as `en_US.UTF-8` that the JVM acts sanely?

Comment: I have'nt got an AIX box at hand for quite some times now unfortunately so i ca'nt confirm but that I really think that will do it.

Comment: Cool.  I appreciate the help - I agree with you that my lack of the UTF-8 language pack is the likely culprit here, but I also can't confirm that, unfortunately.