# Reading files with invalid encoding in filename

Tags: java, file, encoding

I have this code:

```
File dir = new File("/home/user/somedir");
for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
    System.out.println(child.getName());
    if(!child.isDirectory()){
        readLines(child.getPath()); //do something with this file
    }   
}
```

And i get this output:

```
cestino
arabika
wkurwi�%87_si�%99
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/somedir/wkurwi�%87_si�%99 (No such file or directory)
```

`child.renameTo()` also doesn't work.

`new FileReader(child)` instead of `child.getPath()` doesn't work too:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/somedir/wkurwi�%87_si�%99 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
```

I  know if I manually change file name then file can be easliy read. But why this file is listed by listFiles method but i can't read file using this name? Is there any solution? I have a lot of this files with wrong encoding so I cant change all names manually :) But if there is some automatic method to change their names, even file1, file2 is good.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545625/java-cant-open-a-file-with-surrogate-unicode-values-in-the-filename
Maybe it is the same problem.

Comment: This looks like the same problem. THX!