# Unable to read non-UTF8 bytes in the filename using java, causing failure in stat of file

Tags: java, utf-8, file-io, character-encoding, filenames

I have a list of files within a directory and those filenames have non-utf8 characters in their name. When I use java NIO library to read those filenames from the directory and list the files, it fails to read the correct name. The path object that will be created from iterating DirectoryStream will replace all the non-UTF8 characters with `\357\277\275` which corresponds to "?". Is there a way I can read these filenames correctly using java so I can use the list of filenames within a given directory and perform stat on each file in a given directory.

I have written a sample piece of java code which uses NIO library and tries to list down all the entities within the directory. Below is my code:

```
public class FileIteration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the directory path: ");
        String directoryPathStr = scanner.nextLine();

        Path directoryPath = Paths.get(directoryPathStr);

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directoryPath)) {
            Iterator<Path> iterator = directoryStream.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Path entry = iterator.next();
                String fileName = entry.getFileName().toString();

            //String decodedFileName = new String(fileName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println("File: " + fileName);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the an example filename with bytes `8000124463972718\314H2\376\=M\3230U\317\313S\=`
it is supposed to be printed and read as
`8000124463972718ÌH2þ=MÓ0UÏËS=`
but instead I am getting
`8000124463972718?H2?=M?0U??S=` in my path object, which in bytes you can replace each "?" with `\357\277\275`

I had also tried different APIs, same issue was observed with them as well, for example I also tried:

```
public static void printPathsUsingFileWalk(String dir, int depth) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get(dir), depth)) {
            stream.forEach(path -> System.out.println("File name (using stream)"+path));
        }
    }
```

This fails as well.

Encoding of the filenames seems to be ISO-8859-1 and these java APIs seems to be expecting them to be UTF8.
Just in case to make sure I get across my question clearly, the issue is not reading the content of the file, but the filename from the directory. Since I get wrong characters when I try to list down files, I am missing to perform stat on some of the files.

Comment: I am using the value returned by the path object and directly performing a stat on it, that fails as well so there is no involvement of my console in that. Furthermore when you take the bytes i shared and create the file using your console it will encode it with the encoding of your console (which seems to be utf8)

Comment: its more about reading the filename from directory and then being able to perform stat on that file using java

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html
This is what I mean by stat

Comment: Also, I have ensured that those file names print correctly when I print them on my terminal using ISO-8859-1 encoding

Comment: For exampl, in my linux if I convert these filenames from ISO-8859-1 to utf-8
I am able to do that, using below command
# ls > output
# iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF8 output

same command fails when i try to read it as UTF-8

Comment: Hence, I concluded that these java APIs only expect UTF8 when we try to read these filenames. The character are not incorrect in the filename, above command proves that for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Can't Open a File with Surrogate Unicode Values in the Filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545625/java-cant-open-a-file-with-surrogate-unicode-values-in-the-filename)

Comment: @TimMoore Your proposed duplicate specifically relates to surrogate pairs, but this question is more general. Also, that question was raised in 2009, has not received any answers since 2014, and has no accepted answer. If you think this question is a duplicate of that one, can you explain _how_ it resolves the OP's problem, because I don't see it. A question that simply looks somewhat similar to an existing one is not sufficient grounds to close vote.

Comment: Could you put the code which fails in the question, and details of the file and platform encoding? Just having System.out printing something odd isn't proof the character of filename is corrupt, whereas if `Files.readAllBytes(entry)` fails then there is an issue.

Comment: @DuncG the path object that I create, that itself has "?" in it. from iconv, i was able to figure out that the filename has "ISO-8859-1" encoding and my system is on utf8. Tried changing the local to the same but still failed. can you more info on how can I check with readAllBytes(). Accorsing to iconv it is a valid filename

Comment: The code you have shown does not contain the Java code which fails - you mention ls and stat which isn't NIO call to read a file. You ought to check the characters of filename are as expected (not by System.out). The question lacks detail which would help you get an answer.